# Remotely deploying docker containers

Tags: docker, containers

I am running a docker engine on macOS. I am able to launch the containers using python SDK locally. How do I connect to the docker engine remotely?

Comment: Are you using a deploy system, such as ECS AWS, docker swarm, Kubernetes? Or are you just wanting to implement your own system?

Comment: I am trying to use libcloud to deploy containers.I have made some progress with the help of https://serverfault.com/questions/843296/how-do-i-expose-the-docker-api-over-tcp/843332#843332. It helped me expose the APIs over TCP (on ubuntu16.04 - still working on macOS and client side implementation)

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable the REST APIs of the docker engine. These are not enabled by default. I couldn't yet figure out the way to do so on macOS. For ubuntu, you can following the steps from: [Official Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#bind-docker-to-another-host-port-or-a-unix-socket) or alternatively [Ivan Krizsan Blog](https://www.ivankrizsan.se/2016/05/18/enabling-docker-remote-api-on-ubuntu-16-04/)
2. There is option to expose the secure (https) or insecure APIs. In case of secure, you should have access to key and certificate per files.
3. [libcloud documentation](http://libcloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/container/drivers/docker.html) helps in connecting to the remote docker engine and execute commands. The exposed the insecure APIs and following code listed the containers on the server.

   ```
   from pprint import pprint
   from libcloud.container.types import Provider
   from libcloud.container.providers import get_driver

   cls = get_driver(Provider.DOCKER)
   conn = cls(host='http://<ip-address>', port=<port>)
   pprint([repr(image.name) for image in conn.list_images()])
   ```